# using a variable in a <path> element in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am new to svgs, have to work with them.

Since I basically don't really know anythin about CSS, SVG and JS it is hard for me to get into the topic.

My SVG-"Code":

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
  function getCircleX(degrees, radius) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
      degrees=0;
    }
    return Math.cos(degrees*3.14159/180) * radius * (-1);
  }
  function getCircleYup(degrees, radius) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
      degrees=0;
    }
    return Math.sin(degrees*3.14159/180) * radius * (-1);
   }
 function getCircleYdown(degrees, radius) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
      degrees=0;
    }
    return Math.sin(degrees*3.14159/180) * radius;
 }
]]>
</script>

<g>
<path
   id="Path1"
   style="fill:#ff0000;"
   d="M 547.5 161.5 h 17.5 a 17.5 17.5 0 0 1  getCircleX(30,17.5) getCircleYup(30,17.5) z" />
</g>
```

So, I know that this isn't gonna work as I can't call the js function inside my SVG element. But how can I do that?

Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I have read it multiple times and I don't understand how that shall help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tesseract** solution is probably the most direct. What you are trying to accomplish is `interpolation` by inserting value expressions into a string and using `template literals` is easiest way to do so on a modern browser. But you cant interpolate html directly. Html is just the structure of the page, its static. If you want to add values from a function or any other type of thing that is 'dynamic'(after page load) you will need to use javascript.

Please look at the solution below.

```
function getCircleX(degrees, radius) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
    degrees = 0;
  }
  return Math.cos(degrees * 3.14159 / 180) * radius * (-1);
}

function getCircleYup(degrees, radius) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
    degrees = 0;
  }
  return Math.sin(degrees * 3.14159 / 180) * radius * (-1);
}

function getCircleYdown(degrees, radius) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
    degrees = 0;
  }
  return Math.sin(degrees * 3.14159 / 180) * radius;
}

const svg = () => {
  const html = `
    <svg viewBox="500 150 100 20">
      <g>
        <path id="Path1" style="fill:#ff0000;" d="M 547.5 161.5 h 17.5 a 17.5 17.5 0 0 1 ${getCircleX(30,17.5)} ${getCircleYup(30,17.5)} z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  `;
  
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = html;
  
  return template.content;
};

document.body.append(svg());
```

As you can probably see this solution is pretty close to what has already been provided. However, Instead of templating out just the path, Ive templated out the entire svg markup. This has a couple of nice properties such as being simpler to extend. Instead of twiddling dom attributes for each element you want to change(assuming the dom element exists), you can just render everything at once. You just generate the svg you want and add it to the dom. Why might you ask? Well it depends, it looks like you are playing around in js and are probably going to be adding and changing paths. You might want to more and more things configurable, who knows. Look at the example below.

```
const svg = (fill, id) => {
    const html = `
      <svg viewBox="500 150 100 20">
        <g>
          <path id="${id}" style="fill:#${fill};" d="M 547.5 161.5 h 17.5 a 17.5 17.5 0 0 1 ${getCircleX(30,17.5)} ${getCircleYup(30,17.5)} z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    `;
  
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = html;
  
  return template.content;
};

document.body.append(svg('ff0000', 'Path1'));
document.body.append(svg('00ff00', 'Path2'));
```

You can see how easy it is just to change the markup and have the results you want.

The only thing *magical* that is going on is the usage of [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) elements which is designed specifically for the purpose you are trying to achieve. If you are not familiar with template literals, you can read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They are pretty awesome.

The only other feedback I'd add is that well known constants such as PI, E, SQRT of 2 are already defined on the `Math` object. If you are not using a rich JavaScript compatible editor you should try vscode(its free) or similar as it gives you syntax feedback as you type which is super useful if you are starting out.

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to be aware, you can't directly call javascript while in the middle of HTML, so you need to modify (or create) the svg element from within javascript code. Here's an example which uses `setAttribute` to set the path property in javascript (using a template literal to build the string).

This may not be the best way to do what you want - If the SVG you're creating is static, you should run the js once (perhaps in the browser console) to get the results you need. This way it would be visible to people with javascript disabled.

```js
function getCircleX(degrees, radius) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
    degrees=0;
  }
  return Math.cos(degrees*3.14159/180) * radius * (-1);
}
function getCircleYup(degrees, radius) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
    degrees=0;
  }
  return Math.sin(degrees*3.14159/180) * radius * (-1);
}
function getCircleYdown(degrees, radius) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(degrees))) {
    degrees=0;
  }
  return Math.sin(degrees*3.14159/180) * radius;
}
path=`M 547.5 161.5 h 17.5 a 17.5 17.5 0 0 1  ${getCircleX(30,17.5)} ${getCircleYup(30,17.5)} z`
document.getElementById("Path1").setAttribute("d",path)
```

```html
<svg viewBox="500 150 100 20"><g>
<path
   id="Path1"
   style="fill:#ff0000;"
   d="" />
</g></svg>
```

Note that the svg element needs to be present before the js runs - either make sure the js is in a `<script>` tag later in the html than the svg, or put it inside a function which is only run after the document has loaded.

Comment: Thx for the note that the script needs to be executed AFTER the html. I thought I was too dumb to copy-paste. Your Solution helped a lot, as it did brenden's too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the give answers one step further.

Create a **Custom Element**  (your own **dynamic!** HTML tag)

It is a W3C standard, supported in all modern Browsers. (IE11 is not modern, there is a polyfill)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

You can define your Custom Element anytime you want; `<svg-circle>` *automagically* 'executes' when defined. **No restrictions** on code needing to run **AFTER** HTML

When you change an attribute with code (or manually if you edit the HTML in F12 developer tools), the `<svg-circle>` is updated:

`document.querySelector("svg-circle").setAttribute("color", "gold");`

```html
<style>
  svg-circle svg { width: 80px; background: khaki; /* can style svg here */ }
</style>

<svg-circle></svg-circle>
<svg-circle radius="15%" color="green"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle x="0" y="100%" color="blue"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle x="25%" radius="75%" color="magenta"></svg-circle>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["x", "y", "radius", "color"]; // define attributes that trigger change
    }
    connectedCallback() { // execute on first use in HTML
      this.render();
    }
    attributeChangedCallback() { // handle attribute changes
      this.render();
    }
    render() {
      let [ 
        x = "50%", // default values
        y = "50%",
        radius = "50%",
        color = "red"
      ] = this.constructor.observedAttributes.map(x => this.getAttribute(x) || undefined);
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox='0 0 96 96'>` +
           `<circle cx='${x}' cy='${y}' r='${radius}' fill='${color}'/></svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```